# How to make a timer interrupt a waiting process?

Tags: python, timer, wait, interrupt, alarm

I am trying to implement alarms in a program that uses a standard read-eval-print loop.

An example of the code would be something like this:

```
while True:
    input = get_input() # A function that waits for input and 
                        # returns the input once it is obtained
    set_alarm(interpret(input)) # A function that sets the alarm
```

Set_alarm uses the threading.Timer class. There is one problem with this, though. The timer activates on time, but when get_input() is waiting for an input, the timer will wait for that process to complete before producing the required output.

Is there a way for the callback function of the timer to interrupt the waiting function and produce the output immediately after it is activated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[CPython checks for signals](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/582274636446/Python/ceval.c#l1232) between individual pure Python steps.  It is likely that get_input() owns the global interpreter lock and that signal processing will be delayed until get_input returns.

The solution is to use non-blocking calls to solicit user input in a way that respects timeouts.  Depending on your platform, you may be able to use [kbhit](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#module-select) or select (with stdin) to get the user input.

Comment: Alright, thanks! But khbit only applies to keystroke inputs, right? What if get_input() gets input of another form, such as speech?

Comment: @Jian: Then you would need to find some sort of non-blocking way to determine if there was any speech waiting to be or already processed.